# how the screen reader announcement for page log out

Tags: wcag

when I click on logout button, I can see the page gets loaded and there is text displays on the screen.

you have logged out, [click here](https://logout) to login again.

**Actual result**

at this time,Screen reader announces logout button then it was remains silent. and tab focus to the out of the page, if press tab again, focus does not reach on click here link

what should be the expected result?
does it announces the status ?
does the tab focus move to click here link?
does the click here link need descriptive text ?

**Expected result**

After click on log out button

[screen reader announces status ] you have logged out.

[screen reader press tab key focus move to click here link and announces] click here to login again link

**Alternate approach**

[screen reader announces status ] you have logged out.

[screen reader automatically focus move to click here link and announces] click here to login again link.

which approach is more accessible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good number of approaches you could take.

You could make the logout message focusable by giving it a `tabindex` of `0`, and then set focus to that element on page load. You would also need to give the element a `role`, like region, so the screen reader user can infer they haven't landed on a control.

Another approach is to provide an `id` attribute to the logout text, and reference it with an `aria-describedby` attribute on the link.

A third approach would be to wrap the logout text in an `<alert>` tag, which automatically gives it `aria-live="assertive"` and `aria-atomic="true"`. This comes with a gotcha - you would have to make sure the text is hidden to screen readers until after the page loads. Live Live regions report changes in content, so loading one with a static string won't announce it. It'd look something like this:

```
<alert>
  <p id="logoutmessage" aria-hidden="true">
    You have been logged out.
  </p>
</alert>
```

and in your scripts

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("logoutmessage").setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false")
}, 100)
```

Also, it'd be a good idea to make "click here to login again" the text of the link. Users of screen readers often navigate by opening lists of elements on a page, and "click here" doesn't provide enough context on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would prefer first approach when user clicking logout button, then screen reader announces the alert you have logged out, and set focus to click here link so that screen reader again made announcement click here to login link so when user press enter key, page load to login page. because there is no other element in the page, only have a logout text.  pls let me know if its ok